# Python socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, errno

I am trying to write a program for file transfer using sockets. The server end of the code is running fine. However, in the client side I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "client.py", line 54, in <module>
uploadFiles(directory)
File "client.py", line 36, in uploadFiles
transferFile(fname)
File "client.py", line 13, in transferFile     
cs.connect((HOST, 36258))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

My code is as follows

```
import os
import socket

def transferFile(fname):
   HOST = '127.0.0.1'
   CPORT = 36258
   MPORT = 36250
   FILE = fname
   cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   cs.connect((HOST, 36258))
   cs.send("SEND " + FILE)
   cs.close()
   ms = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   ms.connect((HOST, MPORT))
   f = open(FILE, "rb")
   data = f.read()
   f.close()
   ms.send(data)
   ms.close()

def uploadFiles(directory):
   home = os.getenv("HOME")
   folder = str(home + "/" + directory)
   os.chdir(folder)
   dirList = os.listdir(folder)
   print dirList
   for fname in dirList:
       if fname.endswith('.bin'):
           transferFile(fname)

os.chdir(os.getenv("HOME"))
directory = "testdownload"
if not os.path.exists(directory):
   os.makedirs(directory)
 os.chdir(directory)

uploadFiles(directory)
```

I tried looking for help on Google and other posts on Stack Overflow, none of them helped. Can someone please help me? 
The line numbers may be different since I pasted only some part of the code

Comment: How do you know that the server end is working? The error message suggests that the TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:36258 is being refused. What happens when you run `telnet 127.0.0.1 36258`?

Comment: I ran `telnet 127.0.0.1 36258` and was able to see the connection.
`Trying 127.0.0.1...`
`Connected to 127.0.0.1.`
`Escape character is '^]'.`

I checked the server end and found that there was an issue with the sockets not opening up in sync with the client side

Thanks

Comment: To add to the above comment, I added a 2 second delay after the `cs.close()` and after `ms.close()` so as to sync with connections on the server end and it worked like a charm.

Thanks tc

Comment: Please clarify: How can `cs.close()` (client-side) and `ms.close()` (server-side) be in the same code ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem obviously was (as you figured it out) that port 36250 wasn't open on the server side at the time you tried to connect (hence connection refused). I can see the server was supposed to open this socket after receiving `SEND` command on another connection, but it apparently was "not opening [it] up in sync with the client side".

Well, the main reason would be there was no synchronisation whatsoever. Calling:

```
cs.send("SEND " + FILE)
cs.close()
```

would just place the data into a OS buffer; `close` would probably flush the data and push into the network, but it would almost certainly return before the data would reach the server. Adding `sleep` after `close` might mitigate the problem, but *this is not synchronisation*.

The correct solution would be to *make sure* the server has opened the connection. This would require server sending you some message back (for example `OK`, or better `PORT 36250` to indicate where to connect). This would make sure the server is already listening.

The other thing is **you must check the return values of `send`** to make sure how many bytes was taken from your buffer. Or use [`sendall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall).

(Sorry for disturbing with this late answer, but I found this to be a high traffic question and I really didn't like the sleep idea in the comments section.)

Comment: can i use the same port on client side to connect to multiple servers? each server is a just copy of one another. This is just to load balance the requests.

Comment: @y_159, To my knowledge, each server binds to a single port. So having mutliple servers in same port isn't possible. Can anyone verify my claim?