# Django [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a project in django (python 3.4 and django 1.8.2). It's working well on my computer, at localhost:8000.

I use virtualenv for this project, and I tried to install it on another machine.
I set up a virtual env, install django and get my sources from the remote repository.

I run `python manage.py runserver` and the server run, but when I access http://localhost:8000 I got :

```
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py in create_connection, line 500
Python Executable:  /opt/odoo/trois_s/calendar/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.0
```

I've tested on another machine et got same thing, but all is running well on mine.

I've never had this problem before, when getting a remote project and running, maybe someone who faced this could help.

Thanks,

EDIT :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your `settings.py` file, in `DATABASE` section, you may use the config for your machine, but now, in this new machine, password, or root user are diferrent.

Comment: Same issue in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585377/python-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused

Comment: I don't use database here, it's just an interface that call somewebservice.
I've added my settings DATABSE section in post edit