# Connect refused in response to Django runserver

Tags: django, python-3.x

Working my way through a [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), I have run `django-admin startproject mysite`. Now I cannot get the next step to work.

```
$ python manage.py runserver

>>>
$
```

where the blank line is where `Ctrl-C` was entered to break the loop.  The `>>>` was the prompt I defined for the virtualenv. In other words, no output.

Most importantly, I get a connection refused error when connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. I do not get the the "'Welcome to Django' page, in pleasant, light-blue pastel" as described in the tutorial.

For other commands `python manage.py` works correctly. For example:

```
$ python manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

$ python manage.py shell --command 'import sys; print(sys.version)'
3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

$/ python manage.py shell --command 'import django; print(django.__version__)'
1.11.2
```

I am at loss for how explore further. I have tried:

1. Using multiple browsers
2. Varying the IP and port, including using `LOCALHOST`.
3. Turning off the proxy
4. Consulting other Stack Overflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634259/django-errno-111-connection-refused) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802189/django-errno-111-connection-refused)
5. Rebooting my computer
6. Exploring Chrome's log's. Perhaps someone else can get something valueable out of these: [Request Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Lc5.jpg) & [Timing Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjKRn.jpg).

I am at loss for other steps to debug this problem.

Comment: Are you using a browser on the same computer as you are running the server?

Comment: Yes. I am using the Django development server on my local machine. Then I am using a browser on that same machine.

Comment: After entering the ip and hit enter did you see loader? and after killing the server the loader disappeared ?

Comment: Chrome displays "Connecting..." in the bottom status before failing with a connection refused error.

Comment: try to open a [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), just to debug if the problem is django or something else in your computer

Comment: Good idea to pusue!

Answer (score 12):

If you didn't change something in the settings.py you should enter the service in

localhost:8000

Using the same machine where you are runing the server.

If you want to enter from another computer in the same network you should use

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And change your "allowed hosts" to the ip of your computer or to *

Comment: The `python manage.py runserver localhost:8000` does not change the behavior. No output on the command line. Connection refused with a browser.

Comment: please copy paste the lines in your prompt after run, "runserver"

Comment: I placed the lines in the body of the question.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: finally this was the crap missing, wasted couple of hours with the network policies #facepalm