# Importing in Python script running on corporate Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, automation, appium

i am trying to run my python script that works fine locally, on our corporate Jenkins.

On top of the script i have

```
from appium import webdriver
```

and getting this error in Jenkins:

```
File "/home/emobappta/jenkins-workspace/workspace/xz1nwi_Jenkinsfile-1647515865042/Skripte/test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    from appium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium'
```

I have the whole appium folder in the same directory on my bitbucket and at this point no idea what i can try...

By including

```
pprint.pprint(sys.path) "
```

in my Jenkinsfile i get the following output:

```
'/home/emobappta/jenkins-workspace/workspace/xz1nwi_Jenkinsfile-1647515865042/Skripte',
```

'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are referring to by 'appium folder', so I might be entirely confused about what you are asking since you generally don't go around copying libraries when moving projects. However, what I simply see is that the package itself is missing. So try running

```
pip install Appium-Python-Client
```

using a terminal in your corporate server. Check if you are using a venv, which means that its packages are isolated. If that is the case, open a terminal, switch to that venv, and execute the above command.

Comment: the install worked..it seems to be importing, but now i get an errno 111 connection resufed in the driversetup part, trying to connect to the localhost. perhaps any idea how to build a connection to the appium server thats running on my desktop?

Comment: Check if your server port is open. Refer to this answer for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27234405/3730626